# Installing LetsEncrypt on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to install LetsEncrypt for my domains on my Ubuntu server, I've done these before.. Now I'm on another server, and when I try to run `./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com`, I receive this error:

> Failed authorization procedure. www.domain.nl (tls-sni-01):
>   urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient
>   authorization :: Incorrect validation certificate for TLS-SNI-01
>   challenge. Requested
>   24b12211dde2917738675c9e33fd8883.f67ae135c7fed3148764ebe4e009e44e.acme.invalid
>   from 0.0.0.0:443. Received certificate containing '',
>   leeshetetiket.nl (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The
>   client lacks sufficient authorization :: Incorrect validation
>   certificate for TLS-SNI-01 challenge. Requested
>   b7f2fd7903dd65daf58239f7c00abf27.7995b788de04bee09ec907cbc36ff986.acme.invalid
>   from 0.0.0.0:443. Received certificate containing ''
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>    - The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: www.domain.nl    Type:   unauthorized    Detail:
>   Incorrect validation certificate for TLS-SNI-01 challenge.
>   Requested
>   24b12211dde2917738675c9e33fd8883.f67ae135c7fed3148764ebe4e009e44e.acme.invalid
>   from 0.0.0.0:443. Received certificate containing ''
>
> Domain: domain.nl    Type:   unauthorized    Detail:
>   Incorrect validation certificate for TLS-SNI-01 challenge.
>   Requested
>   b7f2fd7903dd65daf58239f7c00abf27.7995b788de04bee09ec907cbc36ff986.acme.invalid
>   from 0.0.0.0:443. Received certificate containing ''
>
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
>   contain(s) the right IP address.

My domain contains the A record(s) pointing to the server, since I'm already managing the domain on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Did you just set up nameservers/added A records? I know I had the exact same problem and I just had to wait for the DNS to propagate.

Comment: I see, well I've did it like 12 hours ago.. thought it'd work by now.

Comment: If you have more than 1 SSL on that server, I think you need to specify the webroot parameter and agree to the TOS, --agree-tos -a webroot --webroot-path=/home/user/public_html.

Comment: Hmm, I do not have more than 1 SSL on the server atm.. But I'll try that

Comment: I've got it working now.. well atleast I've installed the certificate.. But now Chrome is telling me "connection is not secure".

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot?

Comment: I know what I did wrong, need to find out how to add the certificate to my vhosts

Comment: @peurr please consider posting an answer if you got it working so other people can solve their problems as wel.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Let's Encrypt client unreliable, I used [ACME](https://github.com/hlandau/acme). I have a [tutorial available here] for Amazon Linux, but Ubuntu should be much the same[2](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/).